# How does Routing in PHP Yii work?

Tags: php, yii, routes

I come from a Rails and codeIgniter background and I am used to see a routes.rb or routes.php however reading some documentation from the Yii framework I just cannot figure out how routing works? Is it done automatically by the config file? If so then how?

Looking at the main.php config file I believe the following lines create the magic:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

However why is there a w+ inside the controller tag? How does the id tag work?

Why does the url have to start with index.php? Why can't it simply be 
localhost/controllername/action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Yii! The URL Manager is very powerful and you can get it do *almost* anything you need.

The URL doesn't have to start with `index.php` - try these settings:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'showScriptName' => false, // Removes index.php from URL
    'urlFormat'=>'path',       // Uses /controller/action rather than query vars
    'useStrictParsing'=>true,  // Prevents generic rule matching
    'rules'=>array(
    ),
),
```

As for the `+w` in the rules, this is Regex - or rather Yii's basic version of Regex. You can set up parameters in your route and have them only match certain Regex Patterns:

```
// URL /articles/an-article-321 routed to ArticleController and ActionView Method
// I'm setting up the params $_GET['slug'] and $_GET['id']
 'articles/<slug:[a-z-]+>-<id:\d+>' => 'article/view'
```

Comment: It looks as if adding the showScriptName => false makes all of my links broken?

Comment: Are you manually constructing your links, including `index.php/whatever` or are you using `CHtml::link()` or `Controller::createUrl()`? The latter will update when you change your rules. Also are you using .htaccess file to rewrite all your URLs?

Comment: I simply created the auto-generated app and it has some links. After reading an article about removing index.php and about routing I understand that a .htaccess file must be placed at the root of my project www/testdrive in my situation. The file must contain http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x . However it looks as if now the links point towards localhost/site/action which is fine but they all return 404. If I use localhost/index.php/site/action then they work fine

Comment: Also after adding the .htaccess it looks as if the server returns a 500 internal error. Do you need the log?

Comment: There must be some kind of syntax error or permissions problem in the .htaccess file if you're getting a 500.

Comment: Looks like RewriteEngine wasn't on. Silly me

Comment: One more question. The second piece of code that you have posted. Is it a good way to do this? I mean. after reading some more articles I have understood that this should be done automatically. You did it manually here. Is it for explaining purpose ? Does the code actually work?

Comment: It's just an example of what's possible. Yii comes with default rules which you posted. These I suppose are *automatic* in that they send generic URL patterns to a controller and an action. But I like to write my own - then there are no ways into your app that you haven't specified. You'll find yourself writing specific rules anyway as your app grows - might as well learn how to do it from the start.

Comment: I feel more confident working the way you work here. Rails gave me hell because of this. Quitting will be hard. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First, here's a nice guide: http://www.larryullman.com/2013/02/18/understanding-routes-in-the-yii-framework/

To answer your questions (or some of them), the lines you've pasted basically tell Yii  how to handle these 'pretty' urls, for example it expects a controller name, then an id (d+ means digits), and it will route to controller/view.

Also note that there are naming conventions for controllers and actions, eg. UserController, actionView().

Regarding your index.php questions, that is the job of Nginx / Apache htaccess, it should've been the same in CodeIgniter too.

Hope this helped.

P.S. You can read more about URLs here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url